# best technology for live broadcast for ipad/iphone and web

Tags: flash, ipad, live-streaming, flash-media-server

i am looking for alt for broadcast live from my webcam.
i have option to use Flash Media Server but flash is not supported in ipad so what other option i can go with which support ipad/iphones and other mobile devices as well as web.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't use Flash in a web page on iOS devices, you can build a native app using Flash.

[Developing for iOS using Flash Professional](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html)

An app developed this way will allow you to stream live to and from Flash Media Server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out HTTP Live Streaming. It is a streaming video technology that apple has implemented to work on their mobile devices and are bringing it to their desktop platform as well.